# Symfony2 - error while generating PDF file with Tcpdf Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

In my twig template for generating PDF I have:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/myBundle/images/no_avatar.jpg') }}">
```

While I am trying generate PDF, I am getting error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Warning: getimagesize(/bundles/wrbmcisintranetsite/images/no_avatar.jpg): f
ailed to open stream: No such file or directory


Exception trace:
() at /var/www/site/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_images.php:171
Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError() at n/a:n/a
getimagesize() at /var/www/site/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_images.php:171
```

And when I change the path where this image is stored, for exmple:

```
<img src="{{ asset('var/storage/images/no_avatar.jpg') }}">
```

and copy that file without using `assets:install web` it works and image is visible in output PDF file. I want to put file in `MyBundle/Resources/public/images` to have it installed with `assets:install`

Comment: As per the error the getimagesize function is not getting the image to calculate the image size. Check the path is correct or not ? Check the command assets:install web is installing your all assets under the web directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass absolute url for all assets (css included).

in your case can try with `absolute_url` the as example:

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('images/logo.png')) }}" alt="Symfony!" />
```

More info in the [doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)